# Botões, painéis e outras formas no CONSOLE

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6, console

Bom, nesses dias ai, eu to fazendo um Console, muito simples, e fiquei curioso ao ver alguns aplicativos feitos por terceiros super avançados, com Menus, painéis e até botões! Quando você clica neles, eles dão o efeito de clique, uma coisa super avançada.

**Tem alguma assembly, ou projeto de código aberto que eu possa fazer meu projeto de console ter formas, como botões e menus?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existem tais bibliotecas ou projetos para aplicações Console do .NET. Isso porque não faz muito sentido um botão em um console, já que existe o **Windows Forms** (ou ainda o WPF), no qual é super simples utilizar botões e componentes visuais como painéis, pois ele é feito para isso.

Dito isso, se ainda assim você quiser utilizar algo como um botão para o console, pode tentar utilizar PInvoke para acessar um nível mais baixo da API do Windows e obter coordenadas do mouse para criar seu próprio botão. [Esse post no MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c) ensina como pegar as coordenadas do mouse em uma aplicação console. Mas criar um botão a partir disso, se for possível, será complicadíssimo.